# Splitting a hash variable with reduce

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

When invoking `reduce` on an array of hashes, I thought I could split the hash by key and value within the parameters using the () technique. But in this case, it does not appear to work:

```
columns = [
  {"lead"=>["source", 2]}, 
  {"parent"=>["name", 4]}
] 

columns.reduce({}) do |acc, (k,v)|
  puts "k #{k} v #{v}"
end

# k {"lead"=>["source", 2]} v 
# k {"parent"=>["name", 4]} v 
# => nil
```

I expected `k` to be `"lead"` and `v` to be `["source", 2]`. Because columns is an array and not a hash, I cannot do this `(k,v)` to get the key/value pair of hash. Is there another technique I can use in argument list in order to pass the k/v pair rather than having to dissect it in the block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the logic behind this parenthesis is basically a parallel assignment, which doesn't work in your case because each item in the collection is a hash. So practically what you can do it convert each item to array instead:

```
columns = columns.flat_map(&:to_a)
```

[**Demonstration**](https://repl.it/EJPm/1)